# Load observables from inside a model in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a model for a projects view which is very simple. There is a click handler for editing a projects which should load the project data from the server into the model. The click handler is called editProject. All I want is to load my observables from the server. This method from inside the models did not work.

```
this.editProject = function(){
    $.getJSON("/projects/get_by_id", {
        id: "7"
    }).done(function(data){
        ko.mapping.fromJSON(data[0], self);
    });
};
```

Comment: Do you want to replace the entire view-model with `data` or assign it to `this.currentData()` (for example)?

Comment: I don't want to replace the entire view but replace the values of observables on a specific user event. The hard coded id is just for example.

Comment: can you post the html or the model your view maps to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what went wrong because you haven't shown your view or whole view model. How are you initializing your viewmodel before `editProject` is called?

Here's an example with the `editProject` method in a layer above the actual `project`.

- Each project has its own viewmodel, created by calling `ko.mapping.toJS` on a plain object (from the server)
- The initial object already has all properties, but some without values.
- In the success callback of the ajax request, the clicked project is updated by passing it as a second parameter: `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, project)`.

If `data` contains new properties, those won't be available at the time of `ko.applyBindings`, and therefore won't be data-bound.

```js
const $ = fakeJQuery();

// The project should have its own viewmodel with initial data
// probably received from the server during first load
const myProjects =[
  ko.mapping.fromJS({ id: "1", additionalInfo: null }),
  ko.mapping.fromJS({ id: "7", additionalInfo: null })
];

const ViewModel = function() {
  this.projects = ko.observableArray(
    myProjects
  );

  // Take the project to edit as an argument
  this.editProject = function(project) {
    $.getJSON("/projects/get_by_id", project)
      .done(function(data) {
        // Because we have access to the clicked project,
        // we map to its existing viewmodel using `fromJS`
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, project);
      });
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

// Mocks
function fakeJQuery() {
  return {
    // Mock ajax request
    getJSON: function(url, opts) {
      let done = () => true;

      setTimeout(function() {
        // Test data to indicate an update:
        done({
          id: opts.id(),
          additionalInfo: "Test " + opts.id()
        });
      }, 1000);

      return {
        done: cb => done = cb
      };
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: projects">
  <li>
    <code data-bind="text: 'id: ' + id()"></code>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.editProject">edit</button>

    <p>
      Info:
      <strong data-bind="text: additionalInfo"></strong>
      <em data-bind="visible: !additionalInfo()">not loaded</em>
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```